# Test Driven Development in PHP without using PHPUnit

Tags: php, tdd, phpunit

```
class TestCase
{
    public function multiply($a,$b)
    {
        return $a*$b;
    }
}
```

I need to use test cases in PHP. Some websites suggests that to use TDD in PHP, we need to install PHPUnit. For now, I need only knowledge of test cases and using them in PHP to test a program. Is that possible for above PHP code(without installing PHPUnit)?
I have WAMPP to run php.

Comment: Just write code that calls the class method and say "Yay" or "Nay" based on the expected result. Of course you can write tests without PHPUnit. PHPUnit is just a lot of PHP code itself. But to write *proper* tests in a well structured way, PHPUnit already brings a lot to the table that you don't have to reinvent yourself. And it's a really good library, something to be recommended without hesitating.

Comment: What prevents you from just testing it? And apart from that, what prevents you from installing PHPUnit? It runs well on the WAMP platform.

Comment: I have tried to download PHPUnit from http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/test-driven-development-in-php-first-steps/. But couldn't. please give me the link to download PHPUnit framework and help me to using it for implementing TDD(using test cases to test programs)!!!

Comment: [Please don't be a Help Vampire!](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires). Type PHPUnit into Google. Find the main website and follow the installation instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this article written by authors of PHPUnit: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/automating-tests.html

One of the examples from there:

> For a newly created array we expect the count() function to return 0. After we add an element, count() should return 1

```
<?php
    $fixture = array();
    assertTrue(count($fixture) == 0);

    $fixture[] = 'element';
    assertTrue(count($fixture) == 1);

    function assertTrue($condition)
    {
        if (!$condition) {
            throw new Exception('Assertion failed.');
        }
    }
?>
```

You can reinvent the wheel, but why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [simple test](http://www.simpletest.org/), it's a lightweight TDD framework for PHP projects. In order to test it you just need to include one single file in your PHP script.